# Typescript validating all object values while extracting keys as union

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm trying to validate an object literal's values, and at the same time create a union of all the keys as a parameter type to a function.

```js
interface PathValue {
    prop1: string;
    prop2?: number;
}

interface PathDeclaration {
    [key: string]: PathValue;
}

const allPaths: PathDeclaration = {
    'one': {prop1: 'foo'},
    'two': {prop1: 'bar', prop2: 2},
}


function getItem(path: Extract<keyof typeof allPaths, string>) {
    return allPaths[path];
}
```

The problem with this example is that since PathDeclaration is the type of allPaths, and its keys are just generic strings, my `path` parameter can't infer the keys from the object literal anymore.

The only solutions I can think of is to have to declare all the keys in a separate interface (duplicate code), or instead of typing allPaths, I could remove `PathDeclaration` and just type each value like `'one': <PathValue> {prop1: 'foo'},` neither which are very elegant solutions. Is there a way to validate the entire `allPaths` object AND create a key union type from the object literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to initialize `const allPaths` with a generic function to 1) add the [type constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `PathDeclaration` *and* 2) let TS [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) the given object literal type automatically. Only functions can do this in one step.

```
const createPaths = <T extends PathDeclaration>(pd: T) => pd

const allPaths = createPaths({
  'one': { prop1: 'foo' },
  'two': { prop1: 'bar', prop2: 2 },
})
/* 
{
  one: { prop1: string; };
  two: { prop1: string; prop2: number; };
}
 */
```

Above will catch errors:

```
const allPathsError = createPaths({
  'one': { prop3: 'foo' }, // error
  'two': { prop1: 'bar', prop2: "bar" }, // error
})
```

And infer all keys:

```
// path: "one" | "two"
function getItem(path: Extract<keyof typeof allPathsInline, string>) {
  return allPathsInline[path];
}
```

This is also one of the few cases where I like to use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) to make things lean:

```
const allPathsInline = (<T extends PathDeclaration>(pd: T) => pd)({
  'one': { prop1: 'foo' },
  'two': { prop1: 'bar', prop2: 2 },
})
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=32&ssc=3&pln=29&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApzACwGpwDYCuKA3gLABQyyADlAPbUCMAXMgM5hSgDmA3BVVoMATAH5WIAgFsARtH7kAvhQqhIsRCnRYAIhAR44UDMDohkZSsgDaAawgBPVhy4huAXVbac+IguXkFAhmHMgIUBAYEN5syAC8yAA8ACrIEAAekCAAJrHeegZGJmYAfAAU1NmsyQCU8SU02SrkwSCh+Hgx8WERUTFlllQA5GYQQ6zENPRMrEMwdHRDyIoANALIQ2AA7osTUwwsGzJGQyv71MKswstrSjUUAPQAVMgUg8ije0Iz7Jw8vMsFFRtnQvtNDi5-udLshJLJ5ICKAFkE8Hs1Wu08J0MJg2ABRKD0KDdcKRSD9d4jEBjMEMADMs3mixuyAeDzShLoUHWmx24ws50OQ2OUFO0NYACIRRKWWyOUSkfdAsqMWBkB0YgBJEB4UAoBJlFJpTIQHJ5HEFQzGMCmEDlSrVOpxBqVGoDHmjfmTb5CplLVY8kFewWzEVi74w64Bu7NR7s6g4yWjGUAH2QEpBEooMAIIAQNrMyG4EDAmsgUgqieQeMyxnziXsDjoMGQYAc1AgzfVWK1Or1Z0hbhKdXeETABCg5g1OLY2t11OsCaw7n8zSAA)

Comment: This is almost perfect - but I've found an odd glitch. In your `allPathsInline` declartion in your sample, if you add an entry `'three': {prop1: 'foo', prop3: null}`, it does not get marked invalid even though prop3 is not specified in the `PathValue` interface.

Comment: If you want an exact type `PathDeclaration`, you can omit the generics. Then excess property checks will [error at `prop3`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=27&pln=13&pc=38#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApzACwGpwDYCuKA3gLABQyyADlAPbUCMAXMgM5hSgDmA3BVVoMATAH5WIAgFsARtH7kAvhQqhIsRCnRYAIhAR44UDMDohkZSsgDaAawgBPVhy4huAXVbac+IguXkFAhmHMj4eN5sAJIgeKAoALzIABTJ1AAmXhiYegZGJmYAlMgJAHw06YXJllQA5GYQtazENPRMrLUwdHS1yIoANALItWAA7j3NrQwswzJGtf1T1MKswn2DViOYUBCNzULtw109iwcAzBIEeHgBioUUQA)

Comment: So that works for the validation part: `const createPaths = (pd: PathDeclaration) => pd` - but then I lose the key union extraction, and my parameter to getItem becomes just a generic string again.

Comment: Then I would switch to a `Record` type instead of using an index signature. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApzACwGpwDYCuKA3gLABQyyADlAPbUCMAXMgM5hSgDmA3BVVoMATAH5WIAgFsARtH7kAvhQqhIsRCnRYAIhAR44UDMDohkZSsgDaAawgBPVhy4huAXVbac+IguXkFAhmHMj4eN5sAJIgeKAoALzIABQAPADSyBAAHpAgACZs7Jw8AHzJ1PmsAEr6dFD5GQA0aBg+hBClAJTICaU0+V3JllQA5GYQo6zENPRMrKMwdHSjyIpNAsijYADuK9OzDCxbMkajLULUwqzCaxtW25hQEJPTl8eLy+eH1ADMEgQ8HgAoouipyDACCAEGBTOZuBAwFFIFIKm1WABRXLGGGpewOOgwZBgBzUCCEsJAyIxOIgCAtFxlHojZDPMAEKDmcLU2LxazUNrufzgoA).